# Sum of Range: Strange Behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js

From *Eloquent JavaScript*, Chapter 4, I implemented an exercise at the end of the chapter, which requires to write two functions: `sum` and `range`. My solution works fine:

```
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));

function range(from, to, step = 1) {
    let numbers = [];
    for (let i = from; i <= to; i += step) {
        numbers.push(i);
    }
    return numbers;
}

function sum(numbers) {
    sum = 0;
    for (let x of numbers) {
        sum += x;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

However, when I have the first line twice, I get an error:

```
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
console.log(sum(range(1, 10))); // additional line

function range(from, to, step = 1) {
    let numbers = [];
    for (let i = from; i <= to; i += step) {
        numbers.push(i);
    }
    return numbers;
}

function sum(numbers) {
    sum = 0;
    for (let x of numbers) {
        sum += x;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Error message, when invoking with `node sum-of-range.js`:

```
/home/paedu/github.com/patrickbucher/eloquent-javascript/exercises/ch04/sum-of-range.js:2
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
            ^

TypeError: sum is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/paedu/github.com/patrickbucher/eloquent-javascript/exercises/ch04/sum-of-range.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is with:

```
function sum(numbers) {
  sum = 0;  // ***
  for (let x of numbers) {
    sum += x;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Here you're reassigning `sum` and setting it to be equal to the variable `0`. Thus, the next time you call `sum()` as a function, it is instead the number `0` and so will give you the error:

> TypeError: sum is not a function

To fix this, you can declare your variable `sum` as a local variable of the *function* `sum` by using the `let` keyword:

```
function sum(numbers) {
  let sum = 0;  // ***
  ...
}
```

```js
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
console.log(sum(range(1, 10))); // additional line

function range(from, to, step = 1) {
  let numbers = [];
  for (let i = from; i <= to; i += step) {
    numbers.push(i);
  }
  return numbers;
}

function sum(numbers) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let x of numbers) {
    sum += x;
  }
  return sum;
}
```